# AdvancedInstaller - Custom Action VBScript - Property not passed through

Tags: properties, windows-installer, custom-action, advanced-installer

I am currently facing an issue when trying to set a public variable through an VBscript in an Custom Action.
Its regarding the Property `"MYDOMAIN"`.
No matter what I am doing, the value is always 0.

Even setting an `";"` after (example) `Session.Property("MYDOMAIN")="1"` does not solve the issue.

When the VBScript is executed locally the value can be retrieved (at least in the variable).

Please find my script below:

```vb
'~~~ Query My Domain
Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next
Dim objWMISvc : Set objWMISvc = GetObject( "winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2" )
Dim colItems : Set colItems = objWMISvc.ExecQuery( "Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem" )
Dim objSysInfo : Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Dim objComp : Set objComp = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.ComputerName)
Dim objCompDN : objCompDN = objComp.distinguishedName
Dim objItem
Dim strComputerDomain
Dim Session
For Each objItem in colItems
    strComputerDomain = objItem.Domain
    ' If objItem.PartOfDomain Then
        ' WScript.Echo "Computer Domain: " & strComputerDomain
      ' Wscript.Echo "Computername: " & strComputerName
    ' End If
Next
If strComputerDomain = "DOMAIN1.loc" Then
   Session.Property("MYDOMAIN")="1" 
elseif strComputerDomain = "DOMAIN2.loc" Then
   call CheckIRL(objCompDN,"(?:Division-)(8[0-9]\d{1,2}|982)-") 
elseif strComputerDomain = "DOMAIN3.loc" Then
   Session.Property("MYDOMAIN")="3"
Else
    if strComputerDomain = "" then
        Session.Property("MYDOMAIN")="0"
    End if
End if
Sub CheckIRL(strReturnValue, strPattern)
   Dim objRegEx : set objRegex = new RegExp
    objRegex.pattern = strPattern
    objRegex.global = true

   If objRegex.Test( strReturnValue ) Then
      Session.Property("MYDOMAIN") = "6"
   Else
      Session.Property("MYDOMAIN") = "7"
   End If
End Sub
Sub CheckSLO(strReturnValue, strPattern)
   Dim objRegEx : set objRegex = new RegExp
    objRegex.pattern = strPattern
    objRegex.global = true

   If objRegex.Test( strReturnValue ) Then
      Session.Property("MYDOMAIN") = "4"
   Else
      Session.Property("MYDOMAIN") = "5"
   End If
End Sub
```

---

To be honest: I am out of ideas...
A friend inserted the script into an InstallShield project and the Property could be resolved. Any idea is appreciated :)

Comment: How are you sequenced? In the compiled MSI, is MYDOMAIN listed in the [SecureCustomProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/securecustomproperties) list in the property table? (if not, try to add it to the end of the delimited string list of secure properties - as in SecureCustomProperties = PROP1;PROP2;MYDOMAIN;PROP3 etc...)

Comment: Hi Asmul. The property was not in SecureCustomProperties. Regarding your hint I added it but the result is the same (extract from msi log): ---> Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = OLDPRODUCTS;AI_NEWERPRODUCTFOUND;MYDOMAIN;
Property(S): MYDOMAIN = 0 ----> Please note: I am creating an .mst for an msi and included the VBScript. The Custom Action is set to "Immediate Execution".

Comment: How are you sequenced? In the GUI? In the installation sequence? What mode? Immediate or deferred? (the latter would be strange, but possible if you do on error resume next).

Comment: I missed the last part of your previous comment - so you are running in immediate mode and not in the GUI sequence? You are doing repackaging for corporate use or is this for large scale distribution? For complex stuff VBScript is almost un-debuggable (thanks to Microsoft's insistence on killing the language), though it works OK for debugging and testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you trying to debug your VBS action code by inserting a message box ([MsgBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)) in each of your IF block of your VBS code. This is just to make sure your VBS code do indeed set the related property to a value different than 0 before it exits.

Just use a MsgBox statement like this:

```
MsgBox Session.Property("MYDOMAIN")
```

to display the property value.

Then if the VBS do indeed set the property to a value different than 0 before exiting, in this case we will need more details about the exact execution sequence when the property is reverted back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I will give this a try and will come back to you once checked.
In the meantime I created a second msi file to do the config...not the best solution but it seems to work :)